# SVG Blink Issue On Scroll Up/Scroll Down

Tags: svg, css-animations, svg-filters

I have a logo that when you scroll down, it blurs out. When you scroll up, it blurs back in. I am accomplishing this using SVG filters.

**Logic:**

When Scroll Down.
Apply blur filter: url(#filt-blur-out); to SVG letters with class: **fadeMe**

When Scroll Up.
Apply blur filter: url(#filt-blur-in); to SVG letters with class: **fadeMe**

**Issue:**

I am having an issue where the logo briefly disappears for a split second before it resumes animating the blur (in both directions).

***IMPORTANT NOTE:*** This seems to ONLY happen on the **second time** you scroll up and down, and every time after that.

If you know what's causing this, I would be very interested in your answer. So far I've managed to break this a few dozen times, but that's about it.

```js
jQuery(".qodef-page-header").waypoint(
  function(direction) {
    // Target this element and run the up or down animation respectively

    if (direction === "down") {
      $(".fadeMe").addClass("blur-in-fwd");
      $(".fadeMe").removeClass("blur-in-bkw");
      $("#animOut")
        .get(0)
        .beginElement(); // restart the animation
    } else if (direction === "up") {
      $(".fadeMe").addClass("blur-in-bkw");
      $(".fadeMe").removeClass("blur-in-fwd");
      $("#animIn")
        .get(0)
        .beginElement(); // restart the animation
    }
  },

  { offset: "0%" }
);
```

```css
/* Added so you can scroll */
.header-logo {
  height: 2000px;
}
#smooth-logo {
  position: fixed;
}

/* SCROLLING ANIMATIONS */
.blur-in-fwd {
  filter: url(#filt-blur-out);
}
.blur-in-bkw {
  filter: url(#filt-blur-in);
}
#filt-blur-in {
  /*  animation-delay: 0.5s !important;*/
}
```

```html
<!-- SCRIPTS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.1/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>

<!-- SVG LOGO -->
<header class="header-logo qodef-page-header">
  <div id="smooth-logo">
    <svg data-name="big-s" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="275px" height="85px" viewBox="0 0 2036.7197 612">
  <title>Stable Smooth Logo</title>
  
  <!-- Blur Animation -->
  <defs>
    <!-- BLUR IN -->
       <filter id="filt-blur-out" x="-50%" y="-50%" width="200%" height="200%">
         <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="0" result="blurpart">
           <animate id="animOut"
                    attributeName="stdDeviation" from="0" to="50" dur="0.5s" fill="freeze" begin="indefinite"
                    calcMode="spline" keyTimes="0; 1" keySplines="0.550 0.085 0.680 0.530"/>
         </feGaussianBlur>
         <feFlood flood-color="white" flood-opacity="1" result="alphapart">
           <animate attributeName="flood-opacity" from="1" to="0" dur="0.5s" fill="freeze" begin="animOut.begin"
                    calcMode="spline" keyTimes="0; 1" keySplines="0.550 0.085 0.680 0.530"/>
         </feFlood>
         <feComposite in="blurpart" in2="alphapart" operator="in"/>
       </filter>
       
       <!-- BLUR OUT -->
       <filter id="filt-blur-in" x="-50%" y="-50%" width="200%" height="200%">
         <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="50" result="blurpart">
           <animate id="animIn"
                    attributeName="stdDeviation" from="50" to="0" dur="1.2s" fill="freeze" begin="indefinite"
                    calcMode="spline" keyTimes="0; 1" keySplines="0.550 0.085 0.680 0.530" />
         </feGaussianBlur>
         <feFlood flood-color="white" flood-opacity="0" result="alphapart">
           <animate attributeName="flood-opacity" from="0" to="1" fill="freeze" dur="1.2s" begin="animIn.begin"
                    calcMode="spline" keyTimes="0; 1" keySplines="0.550 0.085 0.680 0.530"/>
         </feFlood>
         <feComposite in="blurpart" in2="alphapart" operator="in"/>
       </filter>
     </defs>
  
  <!-- small the -->
  <polygon id="dropIn1" class="dropIn1 dropInAll" points="150.137 367.127 137.813 367.127 137.813 443.443 150.137 443.443 150.137 411.917 234.251 411.917 234.251 398.656 150.137 398.656 150.137 367.127"/>

  <polygon id="dropIn2" class="dropIn2 dropInAll" points="137.813 282.344 179.534 282.344 179.534 334.01 137.813 334.01 137.813 347.139 234.251 347.139 234.251 334.01 191.992 334.01 191.992 282.344 234.251 282.344 234.251 269.212 137.813 269.212 137.813 282.344"/>

  <polygon id="dropIn3" class="dropIn3 dropInAll" points="222.066 172.104 222.066 229.389 191.725 229.389 191.725 181.212 179.534 181.212 179.534 229.389 150.004 229.389 150.004 172.104 137.813 172.104 137.813 242.518 234.251 242.518 234.251 172.104 222.066 172.104"/>


  <!-- BIG S -->
  <path id="bigS" class="fadeMe bigS slideAll" d="M362.2168,367.2317c23.8106,16.6907,51.0516,32.82,83.83,32.82,32.1888,0,56.8072-10.392,56.8072-33.4934,0-22.7209-10.6044-34.0863-70.4407-43.93-59.8364-10.6044-89.757-33.7058-89.757-78.3966,0-46.9588,39.96-79.6635,99.4161-79.6635,36.6579,0,63.8458,7.9425,97.4489,28.7153l-18.0235,37.88c-33.9085-17.7179-47.9607-24.0272-78.4851-24.0272-30.6717,0-49.227,14.75-49.227,35.9591,0,19.3162,10.6044,28.7841,67.4117,38.6325,65.1385,10.98,93.5422,35.2179,93.5422,81.8012,0,49.6124-39.7691,83.9606-109.8293,83.9606-38.3944,0-79.8883-17.5373-102.94-38.04Z"/>

  <!-- BIG T -->
  <polygon id="bigS1" class="fadeMe bigS1 slideAll" points="682.881 444.996 682.881 215.385 581.132 215.385 602.355 171.38 842.615 171.38 821.253 215.385 731.83 215.385 731.83 444.996 682.881 444.996"/>

  <!-- ICON UPPER -->
  <polygon id="bigS2" class="bigS2 slideAll"points="1022.924 362.747 964.44 234.65 909.723 362.747 859.133 362.747 940.211 171.373 989.104 171.373 1070.894 362.747 1022.924 362.747"/>

  <!-- ICON LOWER -->
  <polygon id="bigS3" class="bigS3 slideAll" points="819.226 444.996 839.223 403.871 1090.947 403.871 1110.751 444.996 819.226 444.996"/>

  <!-- BIG B -->
  <path id="bigS4" class="fadeMe bigS4 slideAll" d="M1162.8,444.9959V171.38h126.5218c30.6233,0,54.9008,8.0925,70.2054,23.3971,11.8676,11.8747,17.6358,26.2214,17.6358,43.8714,0,52.9109-39.4831,64.1835-39.4831,64.1835s55.5343,7.9083,55.5343,69.55c0,63.2891-63.0285,72.6141-100.6033,72.6141Zm47.3013-41.1245h82.51c45.3081,0,52.07-24.1155,52.07-38.49,0-15.1989-7.029-39.3074-54.1261-39.3074h-80.453Zm0-117.0149h65.6415c46.0124,0,52.8864-23.6014,52.8864-37.6664,0-23.89-18.2345-36.686-48.7733-36.686h-69.7546Z"/>

  <!-- BIG L -->
  <polygon id="bigS5" class="fadeMe bigS5 slideAll" points="1454.812 444.996 1454.812 171.38 1503.761 171.38 1503.761 401.808 1650.476 401.808 1629.693 444.996 1454.812 444.996"/>

  <!-- BIG E -->
  <polygon id="bigS6" class="fadeMe bigS6 slideAll" points="1694.008 444.996 1694.008 171.38 1898.906 171.38 1878.604 213.328 1742.542 213.328 1742.542 281.122 1856.181 281.122 1835.818 323.07 1742.542 323.07 1742.542 403.04 1898.482 403.04 1878.199 444.996 1694.008 444.996"/>
 </svg>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Browsers sometimes have problems with very large blurs. Also SVG filters (and SMIL) are not given a lot of attention by browser developers. I would suggest you either use a smaller blur or implement with CSS filters - which get a little more love.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I changed the blur from 50 to 5 and sped up the animation. I'll keep this change because I like it better! Unfortunately, it still blinks :( 
Appreciate the efforts!

Comment: I started with filters, but they only affect the parent element, blurring the entire logo (going for no blur on A).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I not really familiar with waypoint JS, but you can see my work at https://jsfiddle.net/b85612w7/22/

Basically i think there some flow conflict between `waypoint.js beginElement`, and `jQuery addClass and removeClass`, so i try hard fix this by adding your animate duration to setTimeout()